# Mongo saving duplicates on first entry

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi I finished the project recently and noticed that in a lists collection creates duplicates the first time saving an item in MongoDb. The first item created is always a duplicate. Please see screenshot attached. Is there any particular reason[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2U8j.jpg) why this is case?

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this should work:

```
app.get('/:customListName', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let foundList = await List.findOne({ name: req.params.customListName });
    if (!foundList) {
      const foundList = new List({
        name: req.params.customListName,
        item: defualtItems
      });
      await foundList.save();
      res.redirect(`/${req.params.customListName}`);
    } else {
      res.render('list', {
        listTitle: foundList.name,
        newListItems: foundList.items
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

I recommend you to read more about async await when writing and saving to database, and about the usage of try-catch blocks when handling errors.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch